# Slow search by LIKE and other values (1 million rows+)

Tags: mysql, php

I'm currently developing a kind of search website where one can search for business companies in my country. The database table has 1 million rows and quite a few colums (42 columns).

But I find it very slow. Is that because of the query I'm executing, or the database?

I have created indexes on several columns wich are used in the search query too, but often when a query is run, it times out on 30 seconds.

The query run would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM companies
WHERE ( navn LIKE ?
      OR keywords LIKE ? )
   AND ( ( forretningsadresse_fylke = ?
           AND ( forretningsadresse_kommune = ?
                  OR forretningsadresse_kommune = ?
                  OR forretningsadresse_kommune = ? ) )
          OR ( forretningsadresse_fylke = ?
               AND ( forretningsadresse_kommune = ?
                      OR forretningsadresse_kommune = ?
                      OR forretningsadresse_kommune = ? ) )
          OR ( forretningsadresse_fylke = ? )
          OR ( forretningsadresse_fylke = ?
               AND ( forretningsadresse_kommune = ? ) ) )
```

Engine: InnoDB.
Collation: utf8 - default collation
[image]

If any other info is needed, please say so. What could I do to speed up the search? Thanks in advance.

Edit: extra info.
Indexed columns: PRIMARY (id), organisasjonsnummer, navn, forretningsadresse_fylke, forretningsadresse_kommune, keywords

Comment: Can you add the actual indexes and execution plan?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by execution plan? I added the indexes though.

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball [use EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to get the execution plan.

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball *I have created indexes on several columns* - learn about multicolumn indexes. MySQL can use only one index (per table if there are multiple joined together) for a query.

Comment: `OR` is a performance killer.  `LIKE '%...'` is a performanc killer.  Neither allow for using indexes.  For your select, the entire table will be scanned.

Comment: Sometimes you can speed things up by turning `OR` into a `UNION` of `SELECTs`.  You could try it on the first two things OR'd -- if you are not using a leading wild card.  `INDEX(navn), INDEX(keywords)`,  Or you could try it on the last 4 things OR'd. `INDEX(forretningsadresse_fylke, forretningsadresse_kommune)`.

Comment: I see an "array" of `kode`, etc, splayed across columns.  Don't design schema that way; use multiple rows in another table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about mysql but in mssql like '%val' is a full scan

Multiple keywords in a varchar(200) column is probably not the best design.  Spit the keyswords into separate words into a separate table with a FK back to company.ID.  So each word would be a row. Then you can search on keyword.value = 'xxx' and use an index.

Comment: I see. Yea, that probably would be better. The website is running locally on my computer atm, and the whole sql scheme is about 349MB big. The companies table alone is about 230MB. But I'll try what you said about having an own keywords table with an FK. Thanks!

Comment: How about I change the primary key to the "organisasjonsnummer" column? Would that be a good choice? Since that column is unique, and I'm not sorting or searching rows by the ID column?

Comment: OK.  Did my answer work for you?